# jQuery FullCalendar : Change the color of every saturday except last saturday in the month

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

Currently I am working on a project where I have implemented a jQuery Fullcalendar.

There are few requirements like:

1. Change the color of every Sunday (as Sundays will be off)
2. Change the color of every Saturday except last in all the months (last Saturday is on)

I have achieved the first task using the CSS

```
.fc-sun {
    background-color: #FFe5e5 !important;
}
```

But I am stuck at trying to achieve the second task.

I have tried to search over the google but could not find that how to do this.

Would like to apply any solution using jquery / Javascript / CSS .

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bznpr41q/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDisplay:` Option is not working on some older version So,try this if you have used old version of full calender try this

```
viewRender: function(view) {
   $(".fc-sun, .fc-sat").addClass("non-working-day");
   $(".fc-sat:not(.fc-other-month)").last().removeClass("non-working-day");
},
```

remove your old css and add this one

```
.non-working-day{
    background-color: #FFe5e5 !important;
}
```

Comment: viewRender works for me .  but still these class are not applying correctly :-(

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the calendar options:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
   $(".fc-sun, .fc-sat").addClass("non-working-day");
   $(".fc-sat:not(.fc-other-month)").last().removeClass("non-working-day");
},
```

This to the css:

```
.non-working-day{
    background-color: #FFe5e5 !important;
}
```

Explanation:

The `viewDisplay` function will get call each this the view is reloaded(e.g. changing months). And each time we need to find the last Saturday for that month. We first add a class to all Saturday's and Sunday's and then we remove that class to the last Saturday since it's a working day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, but what i found is this `viewDisplay` is not working in my project, it works fine with the fiddle i have added .

Comment: anyways, thanks for response mate. i will look for some alternative solution , and yeah your ans helped me a lot so +1 from me..